# Downloading files with names stored in a database

Tags: c++, mysql, html

So, I have a database table with the following fields: `title`, `date`, `text`, `file1`, `file2`, `file3`, `file4`, `file5`. I use it to store news and occasionally, the title of files related to the news. The problem is that different news have a different number of files, ranging from 0 to 5. Now, how can I post the link to the exact number of files every news contain? I tried something like this but it didn't work:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM news WHERE id=1";

$result=mysql_query($query);

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))

{

extract($row);

for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++)

    if($"file".$i!="")?>

    <p><a href="/admin/uploads/<?php echo $"file".$i?>"><?php echo $"file".$i?></a></p>

}
```

Comment: That doesn't look like c++. It does however look a lot like perl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++) {
    $sfile = $row["file$i"];
    if($sfile != "") {
?>
        <p><a href="/admin/uploads/<?php echo $sfile?>"><?php echo $sfile?></a></p>
<?php
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read up on `normalization`.

You probably want to create a second table that would look something like this:

`create table files (id int, file varchar(255));`

You then join to that table on `id` to get all your files.

`SELECT id, file FROM myFirstTable, files WHERE myFirstTable.id = files.id`

(And maybe `GROUP BY id`)